# jQuery basic: How to create a loop with this structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a really simple question but I'm not sure how to search for it on the internet.

I have an empty `<div id="wrap"></div>` that needs to end up looking as following:

```
<div id="wrap>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="apples"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banana"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="orange"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grapes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In jquery I have:

```
$(#wrap).html(''); // need this bit
var fruitArray = ['apples','banana','orange','grapes'];
for (fruit in fruitArray) {
    $('<div class="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'"></div>').appendTo('#wrap').doSomething(); 
}
```

Because I need the div with the fruitArray class to do something, I can't just wrap it around with the container class:

```
$('<div class="container"><div class="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'"></div></div>').appendTo...
```

How can I go about generating the container class in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

```
$('<div class="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'" />')
.appendTo('#wrap')
.wrap('<div class="container" />')
.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fruitArray = ['apples','banana','orange','grapes'];
for (fruit in fruitArray) {
    $('<div class="' + fruitArray[fruit] + '"></div>').appendTo('#wrap').wrap('<div class="container"></div>');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wX6sL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruitArray = ['apples','banana','orange','grapes'];
for (fruit in fruitArray) {
    $('<div class="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'" />').wrap('<div class="container" />').appendTo('#wrap').doSomething();
}
```

OR you can also do it like

```
var fruitArray = ['apples','banana','orange','grapes'];
for (fruit in fruitArray) {
    $('<div class="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'" />').appendTo('#wrap').doSomething().wrap('<div class="container" />');
// this will work if the doSomething is a jquery/plugin method that is using chaining (usually they do)
}
```